# Blackberry webworks app and push notification

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, blackberry-webworks

after many days searching online, I never found an answer to my problem or even anyone that has managed to do what I'm trying.

I'm trying to implement push notifications in a WebWorks App for Blackberry but without any luck. I've tried using the demos from Blackberry but even those don't seem to work (and most of them are for native apps in java) and there is not feedback whatsoever from BlackBerry support teams.

What I'd like to know is if this is possible, if someone has done it and if someone has a working sample of it for me to guide on.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You first need to register for the Blackberry Push service [here](https://www.blackberry.com/profile/?eventId=8121)

They will then send you an email in a couple of days with the app ID, port and push initiator password etc.

On the client side you can then listen for push requests:

```
var port = 100; // Change this to the port you received from RIM
var appId = "The app ID you received from RIM";

var serverUrl = "http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com";
var max = 100;

var wakeUpPage = "index.html";

function init() {
    var ops = {port : port, appId : appId, serverUrl : serverUrl, wakeUpPage : wakeUpPage, maxQueueCap : max};
blackberry.push.openBISPushListener(ops, pushReceive, pushRegister, simChange);
}


function pushReceive(data) {
    try {
        var message = blackberry.utils.blobToString(data.payload);
        return 0;
    }
    catch(err) {
    }
}

function pushRegister(status) {
if (status == 0) {
  alert("success");
}
else if (status == 1) {
  alert("network error");
}
else if (status == 2) {
  alert("rejected by server");
}
else if (status == 3) {
  alert("invalid parameters");
}
else if (status == -1) {
  alert("general error");
}
else {
  alert("unknown status");
}
}

window.onload = function() {
    init();
}
```

Also make sure you have `<feature id="blackberry.push" />` and `<feature id="blackberry.utils" />` in your config.xml.

What I also noted was that when the app is closed the pushReceive() doesn't get called. You can bypass this by running the app in the background:

```
function handleExit() {
    blackberry.app.requestBackground();
}

blackberry.app.event.onExit(handleExit);
```

and use `blackberry.app.requestForeground();` to bring app to the front.

The other thing which took me a while to figure out was that it might take a while before pushRegister() is called (this registers the PIN on BIS).
So make sure this gets called otherwise you will never be able to receive push messages.

Comment: I am getting status as 1 (network error) by using this code. Please suggest solution

Comment: Hi thanks for code. I am using same code, but getting network error when registering. Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: Have you registered your SIM card for BIS?

Comment: Yes I have registered for BIS, but still response from server.

Comment: Besides actual network errors all I can think of is: Did you register for push services and receive an email from RIM with your port and app id? If so did you replace port/appId with your values you received in that mail? If you registered for evaluation use pushapi.eval.blackberry.com and for production use pushapi.na.blackberry.com

Comment: I have replaced everything as per code above, but still I am getting same error. Do we need to configure server side/ or do some setting there by our own or we can directly access push.??

Comment: Nothing happens on your server side, your client/phone handles the push request to blackberry.com. Try checking your device logs for errors (on your phone's Home Screen, hold down the alt key and press LGLG) or see if there's anything in Web inspector.

Comment: I was able to get push notification with same code, but when tried with production service, i am getting response "rejected by server"

Answer (score 2):

Push service in a WebWorks app is possible and can definitely be achieved. The [Push API](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.push.html) has more details on using BIS and BES push service in WebWorks. Our support forums also have a fully complete [BlackBerry Push Sample App](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Sample-Emergency-Contact-List-Application-Demonstrating-Push/ta-p/1227875) available for you to use as a reference – the files are available for download at the end of the article.